# CSS help: active button not changing style

Tags: html, css, button

I have a set of 3 buttons (although one is hidden), but when a button is active, i.e. has been clicked, its background colour does not change from #36A9E1 to #F9B233. The :hover state behaves fine; it's only the :active state that is being funny.

Strangely, when I open the webpage up using Inspect in Chrome, then click one of the buttons, it works fine. As soon as I click off the developer tools, it reverts to the default background colour.

Link: http://whatsondv.co.uk/prbok/clipperdesctabs.html.

What could be the issue?

```css
.tablinksClipper{   
    background-color:#36A9E1;
    padding:0.5em;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
    font-family:Sintony, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.25em;
    border:none;
    transition:0.3s;
}

.tablinksClipper:hover{
    background-color:#F9B233;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.tablinksClipper:active{
    background-color:#000000!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinksClipper" onclick="openSectionClipper(event, 'infoClipper')" id="defaultClipper"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> About</button>
  <button class="tablinksClipper" onclick="openSectionClipper(event, 'photosClipper')"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> Photos</button>
  <button style="display:none;" class="tablinksClipper" onclick="openSectionClipper(event, 'dogsClipper')" id="dogTabClipper"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your active state work fine in this snippet. Add different color to the active state and click on the button. You'll see difference between hover and active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state active is only set for the duration of the click.

```css
button:active {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button >Click me</button>
```

If you want the button to have a different look after you clicked it, you might have to add a class to it on click.

```js
function clicked() {
    var element = document.getElementById("button");
    element.classList.add("clicked");
}
```

```css
button.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onClick=clicked()>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `:active` on the button, add a class `.active` dynamically using jQuery.

```
$('.tablinksClipper ').on('click', function(){

$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

and then you can use

```
.tablinksClipper .active {
       background-color:#F9B233 !important;
}
```